# How to remove white infills from svg using php or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, svg

Am wondering how can we remove white infills from this svg with transparent background. In case of png we have pixels and using loop on pixel data we can target white pixel to remove them. however in svg we do not have pixels so any idea how to target those white infills

Sample SVG download link :
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lKOhnOp0gDj6Nqqam-pDM37Lfp_0rSpl/view?usp=sharing
[image]

**UPDATE** : added single letter code

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="771pt" height="310pt" viewBox="0 0 771 310" version="1.1">
<g>

   <path
      id="path94"
      d="m 68.378906,235.66406 -0.265625,0.0117 -0.464843,0.10547 -0.214844,0.0625 -0.203125,0.0664 -0.183594,0.0859 -0.167969,0.082 -0.132812,0.082 -0.128906,0.0859 -0.117188,0.0625 -0.08594,0.0664 -0.06641,0.0508 -0.05078,0.0508 -0.03125,0.0156 -0.01563,0.0195 -0.148437,0.16406 -0.152344,0.16797 -0.117188,0.18359 -0.09766,0.1836 -0.167969,0.34765 -0.09766,0.33203 -0.07031,0.28516 -0.01563,0.13281 -0.01953,0.0977 -0.01172,0.10156 v 0.11719 l 0.01172,0.29687 0.05078,0.28516 0.06641,0.25 0.08594,0.21484 0.06641,0.16797 0.06641,0.13282 0.05078,0.0664 0.01563,0.0352 0.183594,0.19922 0.199219,0.18359 0.214843,0.16797 0.214844,0.13281 0.203125,0.0977 0.148438,0.0664 0.06641,0.0312 0.05078,0.0195 0.01563,0.0195 h 0.01953 l -0.386718,0.11328 -0.3125,0.14844 -0.28125,0.1875 -0.234375,0.16406 -0.183594,0.16406 -0.136719,0.13672 -0.06641,0.082 -0.03125,0.0156 v 0.0195 l -0.183594,0.30078 -0.148437,0.3125 -0.101563,0.30078 -0.06641,0.30078 -0.03516,0.26563 -0.01563,0.11328 v 0.10156 l -0.01563,0.0664 v 0.11718 l 0.01563,0.26953 0.03516,0.26172 0.05078,0.25391 0.06641,0.24609 0.164063,0.41797 0.08594,0.19922 0.09766,0.16797 0.101562,0.16406 0.08203,0.13672 0.101563,0.11719 0.06641,0.0977 0.06641,0.082 0.08203,0.082 0.01563,0.0195 0.199218,0.18359 0.21875,0.14844 0.234375,0.13281 0.234375,0.11719 0.214844,0.082 0.234375,0.0859 0.445313,0.11719 0.203125,0.0469 0.179687,0.0352 0.167969,0.0156 0.148437,0.0156 0.117188,0.0195 h 0.167969 l 0.316406,-0.0195 0.285156,-0.0312 0.28125,-0.0508 0.265625,-0.0508 0.230469,-0.082 0.234375,-0.082 0.21875,-0.0859 0.179687,-0.10156 0.167969,-0.0977 0.152344,-0.0859 0.117187,-0.0781 0.117188,-0.0859 0.07813,-0.0508 0.05078,-0.0469 0.05078,-0.0508 0.183594,-0.20313 0.167969,-0.19531 0.128906,-0.20312 0.117188,-0.21485 0.117187,-0.20312 0.08594,-0.21485 0.117187,-0.3789 0.04687,-0.1875 0.03516,-0.16407 0.01563,-0.15234 0.01953,-0.11719 0.01563,-0.0977 v -0.14844 l -0.01563,-0.38672 -0.07031,-0.34766 -0.09766,-0.3164 -0.101563,-0.26563 -0.09766,-0.21875 -0.101562,-0.16406 -0.06641,-0.0977 -0.01953,-0.0195 v -0.0156 l -0.230469,-0.26563 -0.25,-0.23437 -0.265625,-0.1836 -0.25,-0.16796 -0.230468,-0.11329 -0.203125,-0.0859 -0.06641,-0.0312 -0.05078,-0.0195 -0.03125,-0.0117 H 70.3125 l 0.300781,-0.13672 0.246094,-0.14844 0.21875,-0.15234 0.183594,-0.14844 0.128906,-0.13281 0.101563,-0.0977 0.06641,-0.0703 0.01953,-0.0312 0.148438,-0.23438 0.101562,-0.23437 0.07813,-0.23047 0.05078,-0.23438 0.03516,-0.18359 0.01953,-0.14844 v -0.13281 l -0.01953,-0.23437 -0.01563,-0.21875 -0.117188,-0.41407 -0.148437,-0.36328 -0.167969,-0.32031 -0.167969,-0.24609 -0.08203,-0.10157 -0.06641,-0.10156 -0.148438,-0.14844 -0.183594,-0.15234 -0.183593,-0.14844 -0.199219,-0.11719 -0.199219,-0.0977 -0.402344,-0.15235 -0.398437,-0.0977 -0.164063,-0.0508 -0.167968,-0.0156 -0.152344,-0.0195 -0.132813,-0.0117 -0.09766,-0.0195 h -0.148437 z m 0,0"
      style="fill:#ff00f3;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:none" />
   <path
      id="path218"
      d="m 68.542969,236.8125 h 0.136719 l 0.28125,0.0156 0.269531,0.0625 0.214844,0.0859 0.199218,0.0977 0.152344,0.10156 0.113281,0.082 0.08203,0.0703 0.01953,0.0156 0.183594,0.21484 0.132812,0.21875 0.09766,0.21485 0.07031,0.19922 0.03125,0.18359 0.03516,0.14844 v 0.13672 l -0.01953,0.26171 -0.06641,0.25391 -0.08203,0.21484 -0.101562,0.1836 -0.09766,0.14844 -0.08594,0.10156 -0.06641,0.082 -0.01563,0.0156 -0.199219,0.16797 -0.234375,0.13282 -0.214844,0.082 -0.214843,0.0664 -0.203125,0.0352 -0.148438,0.0156 -0.09766,0.0195 h -0.03516 l -0.300782,-0.0195 -0.265625,-0.0664 -0.234375,-0.082 -0.199218,-0.0977 -0.148438,-0.0859 -0.117187,-0.082 -0.08594,-0.0664 -0.01172,-0.0195 -0.167968,-0.19921 -0.132813,-0.23047 -0.08594,-0.21875 -0.06641,-0.21485 -0.03125,-0.18359 -0.01953,-0.14844 -0.01172,-0.10156 v -0.0352 l 0.01172,-0.26172 0.06641,-0.23437 0.08594,-0.21875 0.09766,-0.18359 0.08594,-0.14844 0.08203,-0.11719 0.06641,-0.0664 0.01953,-0.0156 0.214844,-0.18359 0.214844,-0.13282 0.234375,-0.0859 0.214844,-0.0625 0.199218,-0.0352 z m 0,0"
      style="fill:#ffffff;fill-opacity:0;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:none" />
</g>
</svg>
```

**UPDATE 2** : set fill property to none also had changed opacity

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="771pt" height="310pt" viewBox="0 0 771 310" version="1.1">
<g id="surface1">

    <path
       id="path94"
       d="m 68.378906,235.66406 -0.265625,0.0117 -0.464843,0.10547 -0.214844,0.0625 -0.203125,0.0664 -0.183594,0.0859 -0.167969,0.082 -0.132812,0.082 -0.128906,0.0859 -0.117188,0.0625 -0.08594,0.0664 -0.06641,0.0508 -0.05078,0.0508 -0.03125,0.0156 -0.01563,0.0195 -0.148437,0.16406 -0.152344,0.16797 -0.117188,0.18359 -0.09766,0.1836 -0.167969,0.34765 -0.09766,0.33203 -0.07031,0.28516 -0.01563,0.13281 -0.01953,0.0977 -0.01172,0.10156 v 0.11719 l 0.01172,0.29687 0.05078,0.28516 0.06641,0.25 0.08594,0.21484 0.06641,0.16797 0.06641,0.13282 0.05078,0.0664 0.01563,0.0352 0.183594,0.19922 0.199219,0.18359 0.214843,0.16797 0.214844,0.13281 0.203125,0.0977 0.148438,0.0664 0.06641,0.0312 0.05078,0.0195 0.01563,0.0195 h 0.01953 l -0.386718,0.11328 -0.3125,0.14844 -0.28125,0.1875 -0.234375,0.16406 -0.183594,0.16406 -0.136719,0.13672 -0.06641,0.082 -0.03125,0.0156 v 0.0195 l -0.183594,0.30078 -0.148437,0.3125 -0.101563,0.30078 -0.06641,0.30078 -0.03516,0.26563 -0.01563,0.11328 v 0.10156 l -0.01563,0.0664 v 0.11718 l 0.01563,0.26953 0.03516,0.26172 0.05078,0.25391 0.06641,0.24609 0.164063,0.41797 0.08594,0.19922 0.09766,0.16797 0.101562,0.16406 0.08203,0.13672 0.101563,0.11719 0.06641,0.0977 0.06641,0.082 0.08203,0.082 0.01563,0.0195 0.199218,0.18359 0.21875,0.14844 0.234375,0.13281 0.234375,0.11719 0.214844,0.082 0.234375,0.0859 0.445313,0.11719 0.203125,0.0469 0.179687,0.0352 0.167969,0.0156 0.148437,0.0156 0.117188,0.0195 h 0.167969 l 0.316406,-0.0195 0.285156,-0.0312 0.28125,-0.0508 0.265625,-0.0508 0.230469,-0.082 0.234375,-0.082 0.21875,-0.0859 0.179687,-0.10156 0.167969,-0.0977 0.152344,-0.0859 0.117187,-0.0781 0.117188,-0.0859 0.07813,-0.0508 0.05078,-0.0469 0.05078,-0.0508 0.183594,-0.20313 0.167969,-0.19531 0.128906,-0.20312 0.117188,-0.21485 0.117187,-0.20312 0.08594,-0.21485 0.117187,-0.3789 0.04687,-0.1875 0.03516,-0.16407 0.01563,-0.15234 0.01953,-0.11719 0.01563,-0.0977 v -0.14844 l -0.01563,-0.38672 -0.07031,-0.34766 -0.09766,-0.3164 -0.101563,-0.26563 -0.09766,-0.21875 -0.101562,-0.16406 -0.06641,-0.0977 -0.01953,-0.0195 v -0.0156 l -0.230469,-0.26563 -0.25,-0.23437 -0.265625,-0.1836 -0.25,-0.16796 -0.230468,-0.11329 -0.203125,-0.0859 -0.06641,-0.0312 -0.05078,-0.0195 -0.03125,-0.0117 H 70.3125 l 0.300781,-0.13672 0.246094,-0.14844 0.21875,-0.15234 0.183594,-0.14844 0.128906,-0.13281 0.101563,-0.0977 0.06641,-0.0703 0.01953,-0.0312 0.148438,-0.23438 0.101562,-0.23437 0.07813,-0.23047 0.05078,-0.23438 0.03516,-0.18359 0.01953,-0.14844 v -0.13281 l -0.01953,-0.23437 -0.01563,-0.21875 -0.117188,-0.41407 -0.148437,-0.36328 -0.167969,-0.32031 -0.167969,-0.24609 -0.08203,-0.10157 -0.06641,-0.10156 -0.148438,-0.14844 -0.183594,-0.15234 -0.183593,-0.14844 -0.199219,-0.11719 -0.199219,-0.0977 -0.402344,-0.15235 -0.398437,-0.0977 -0.164063,-0.0508 -0.167968,-0.0156 -0.152344,-0.0195 -0.132813,-0.0117 -0.09766,-0.0195 h -0.148437 z m 0,0"
       style="fill:#ff00f3;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:none" />
    <path
       id="path218"
       d="m 68.542969,236.8125 h 0.136719 l 0.28125,0.0156 0.269531,0.0625 0.214844,0.0859 0.199218,0.0977 0.152344,0.10156 0.113281,0.082 0.08203,0.0703 0.01953,0.0156 0.183594,0.21484 0.132812,0.21875 0.09766,0.21485 0.07031,0.19922 0.03125,0.18359 0.03516,0.14844 v 0.13672 l -0.01953,0.26171 -0.06641,0.25391 -0.08203,0.21484 -0.101562,0.1836 -0.09766,0.14844 -0.08594,0.10156 -0.06641,0.082 -0.01563,0.0156 -0.199219,0.16797 -0.234375,0.13282 -0.214844,0.082 -0.214843,0.0664 -0.203125,0.0352 -0.148438,0.0156 -0.09766,0.0195 h -0.03516 l -0.300782,-0.0195 -0.265625,-0.0664 -0.234375,-0.082 -0.199218,-0.0977 -0.148438,-0.0859 -0.117187,-0.082 -0.08594,-0.0664 -0.01172,-0.0195 -0.167968,-0.19921 -0.132813,-0.23047 -0.08594,-0.21875 -0.06641,-0.21485 -0.03125,-0.18359 -0.01953,-0.14844 -0.01172,-0.10156 v -0.0352 l 0.01172,-0.26172 0.06641,-0.23437 0.08594,-0.21875 0.09766,-0.18359 0.08594,-0.14844 0.08203,-0.11719 0.06641,-0.0664 0.01953,-0.0156 0.214844,-0.18359 0.214844,-0.13282 0.234375,-0.0859 0.214844,-0.0625 0.199218,-0.0352 z m 0,0"
       style="fill:none;fill-opacity:0;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:none" />
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: I suspect that you may fix it by adding fill-rule="evenodd" to the svg element. If this is not solving your problem can you edit your question and add the code for one letter/number?

Comment: @enxaneta i noticed `fill-rule="evenodd"` is by default in file can u check i added single letter code . thanks

Comment: @user889030 i think they've let the kids out early, i also took the time to write a question, well presented and formatted and full of detail and i got 3 downvotes within 5 minutes of posting the question because of a simple error I'd overlooked. I've upvoted you as i thought this was a well written question that someone else might find useful.

Comment: @CraigStanfield ya they should know that its stackoverflow not some English learning forum where its ok to downvote to highlight grammar mistakes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the code in your question the hole in the 8 is a different path. In order to make it a real hole I've merged the 2 paths by combining the d attributes.

However it may not work for all the paths in your code. Give it a try and let me know how it works.

Please observe that I've changed the initial m comand to M when merging the 2 d attributes.

Also: in this case the fill-rule="evenodd" is not required but it may help for other paths.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="771pt" height="310pt" viewBox="64 235 10 15" version="1.1">
<g id="surface1">

    <path
       id="path94"
       d="m 68.378906,235.66406 -0.265625,0.0117 -0.464843,0.10547 -0.214844,0.0625 -0.203125,0.0664 -0.183594,0.0859 -0.167969,0.082 -0.132812,0.082 -0.128906,0.0859 -0.117188,0.0625 -0.08594,0.0664 -0.06641,0.0508 -0.05078,0.0508 -0.03125,0.0156 -0.01563,0.0195 -0.148437,0.16406 -0.152344,0.16797 -0.117188,0.18359 -0.09766,0.1836 -0.167969,0.34765 -0.09766,0.33203 -0.07031,0.28516 -0.01563,0.13281 -0.01953,0.0977 -0.01172,0.10156 v 0.11719 l 0.01172,0.29687 0.05078,0.28516 0.06641,0.25 0.08594,0.21484 0.06641,0.16797 0.06641,0.13282 0.05078,0.0664 0.01563,0.0352 0.183594,0.19922 0.199219,0.18359 0.214843,0.16797 0.214844,0.13281 0.203125,0.0977 0.148438,0.0664 0.06641,0.0312 0.05078,0.0195 0.01563,0.0195 h 0.01953 l -0.386718,0.11328 -0.3125,0.14844 -0.28125,0.1875 -0.234375,0.16406 -0.183594,0.16406 -0.136719,0.13672 -0.06641,0.082 -0.03125,0.0156 v 0.0195 l -0.183594,0.30078 -0.148437,0.3125 -0.101563,0.30078 -0.06641,0.30078 -0.03516,0.26563 -0.01563,0.11328 v 0.10156 l -0.01563,0.0664 v 0.11718 l 0.01563,0.26953 0.03516,0.26172 0.05078,0.25391 0.06641,0.24609 0.164063,0.41797 0.08594,0.19922 0.09766,0.16797 0.101562,0.16406 0.08203,0.13672 0.101563,0.11719 0.06641,0.0977 0.06641,0.082 0.08203,0.082 0.01563,0.0195 0.199218,0.18359 0.21875,0.14844 0.234375,0.13281 0.234375,0.11719 0.214844,0.082 0.234375,0.0859 0.445313,0.11719 0.203125,0.0469 0.179687,0.0352 0.167969,0.0156 0.148437,0.0156 0.117188,0.0195 h 0.167969 l 0.316406,-0.0195 0.285156,-0.0312 0.28125,-0.0508 0.265625,-0.0508 0.230469,-0.082 0.234375,-0.082 0.21875,-0.0859 0.179687,-0.10156 0.167969,-0.0977 0.152344,-0.0859 0.117187,-0.0781 0.117188,-0.0859 0.07813,-0.0508 0.05078,-0.0469 0.05078,-0.0508 0.183594,-0.20313 0.167969,-0.19531 0.128906,-0.20312 0.117188,-0.21485 0.117187,-0.20312 0.08594,-0.21485 0.117187,-0.3789 0.04687,-0.1875 0.03516,-0.16407 0.01563,-0.15234 0.01953,-0.11719 0.01563,-0.0977 v -0.14844 l -0.01563,-0.38672 -0.07031,-0.34766 -0.09766,-0.3164 -0.101563,-0.26563 -0.09766,-0.21875 -0.101562,-0.16406 -0.06641,-0.0977 -0.01953,-0.0195 v -0.0156 l -0.230469,-0.26563 -0.25,-0.23437 -0.265625,-0.1836 -0.25,-0.16796 -0.230468,-0.11329 -0.203125,-0.0859 -0.06641,-0.0312 -0.05078,-0.0195 -0.03125,-0.0117 H 70.3125 l 0.300781,-0.13672 0.246094,-0.14844 0.21875,-0.15234 0.183594,-0.14844 0.128906,-0.13281 0.101563,-0.0977 0.06641,-0.0703 0.01953,-0.0312 0.148438,-0.23438 0.101562,-0.23437 0.07813,-0.23047 0.05078,-0.23438 0.03516,-0.18359 0.01953,-0.14844 v -0.13281 l -0.01953,-0.23437 -0.01563,-0.21875 -0.117188,-0.41407 -0.148437,-0.36328 -0.167969,-0.32031 -0.167969,-0.24609 -0.08203,-0.10157 -0.06641,-0.10156 -0.148438,-0.14844 -0.183594,-0.15234 -0.183593,-0.14844 -0.199219,-0.11719 -0.199219,-0.0977 -0.402344,-0.15235 -0.398437,-0.0977 -0.164063,-0.0508 -0.167968,-0.0156 -0.152344,-0.0195 -0.132813,-0.0117 -0.09766,-0.0195 h -0.148437 z
          M 68.542969,236.8125 h 0.136719 l 0.28125,0.0156 0.269531,0.0625 0.214844,0.0859 0.199218,0.0977 0.152344,0.10156 0.113281,0.082 0.08203,0.0703 0.01953,0.0156 0.183594,0.21484 0.132812,0.21875 0.09766,0.21485 0.07031,0.19922 0.03125,0.18359 0.03516,0.14844 v 0.13672 l -0.01953,0.26171 -0.06641,0.25391 -0.08203,0.21484 -0.101562,0.1836 -0.09766,0.14844 -0.08594,0.10156 -0.06641,0.082 -0.01563,0.0156 -0.199219,0.16797 -0.234375,0.13282 -0.214844,0.082 -0.214843,0.0664 -0.203125,0.0352 -0.148438,0.0156 -0.09766,0.0195 h -0.03516 l -0.300782,-0.0195 -0.265625,-0.0664 -0.234375,-0.082 -0.199218,-0.0977 -0.148438,-0.0859 -0.117187,-0.082 -0.08594,-0.0664 -0.01172,-0.0195 -0.167968,-0.19921 -0.132813,-0.23047 -0.08594,-0.21875 -0.06641,-0.21485 -0.03125,-0.18359 -0.01953,-0.14844 -0.01172,-0.10156 v -0.0352 l 0.01172,-0.26172 0.06641,-0.23437 0.08594,-0.21875 0.09766,-0.18359 0.08594,-0.14844 0.08203,-0.11719 0.06641,-0.0664 0.01953,-0.0156 0.214844,-0.18359 0.214844,-0.13282 0.234375,-0.0859 0.214844,-0.0625 0.199218,-0.0352 z m 0,0"  style="fill:#ff00f3;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:none" />
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: cool , can u share logic or some code that can be used to Merage two paths . thanks . also one more stupid question svg file have a lot of paths am wondering how i will find pairs that two paths are over one another and need to be merged .

Comment: You concatenate the 2 d attributes changing the initial m comand to M. In my answer I've aded a line break so that you can understand it better

Comment: one another Question any how can we find width and height of svg path

Comment: For this you can use the getBBox() method. This is returning an object with the position (x,y) and the size (width, height) of the bounding box of the path

Answer (score 1):

SVG files are just text.
A quick and very very dirty way using regex:

```php
preg_replace("/(<path.*fill:rgb\(100%,100%,100%\).+?)\/>/i", '', file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '/myfile.svg'));
```

However, parsing XML with regex isn't the best and this *will* break if your white shapes in any other file are not represented as paths with fill:rgb(100%,100%,100%)

Ideally you would:

- Open the SVG file as an XML file using SimpleXML or DOMDocument or a third party library
- Find all paths with a fill declared in their styles
- See if the fill value evaluates to white with all different syntaxes (rgb(100%, 100%, 100%), #fff, etc.)
- If so, remove the element.

Comment: That won't work as is.  `fill` defaults to black.  So removing it will just make the holes change from white to black.  You'll need to replace it with `fill="none"`.